# What issues are there running VM images for large Visual Studio Projects instead of imaging PCs?

Tags: virtual-machines, hyper-v, visual-studio

We have been running HyperV VMs for a few years now as development machines, as it is a quick and easy way to manage, update and replace enviroments.

Of late Visual Studio, with upwards, if not more than, 50 projects per solution has become unresponsive much of the time, losing our team hours of development a week.

A contractor recently argued that VMs are notoriously bad at file IO and a terrible solution for Dev environments, and we should be running images on PCs, installed with software like BartPE or Ghost (excuse my dated references, it's been a while since I played in that space) to allow for the quick SOE updating we were wanting with VMs.

I was wondering if this is really is a limitation of VMs, and, if so, are there any sources available I could use to convince the budget owning management of this.

Comment: `if this is really is a limitation of VMs`. It isn't. More likely the hardware is underpowered or oversubscribed.

Comment: @GregAskew thanks for the input

Comment: If this were true, then virtualization wouldn't be the behemoth that it is, and AWS and Azure would certainly not be growing at the rate they're growing. Just like a physical machine, if your virtualization host doesn't have the physical resources to support the workloads, then the workloads are going to suffer. What's your underlying disk infrastructure? What kind of storage, controllers, drives, etc.?

Comment: @joeqwerty Thanks, looks like I'm pushing for a VM environment upgrade then :) TBH much simpler a request than a new PC for all devs